#include в .h (header files) хороший тон? Си
есть модуль quadratic_equation (q_e далее) разделенный на q_e.c и q_e.h и функция solve_equation() объявленная в q_e.h.
Я хочу поставить выходной тип данных объявленный в библиотеке stdint.h, будет ли хорошим тоном использовать #include в файлах заголовков, а если нет как мне сделать это правильно?
p.s.
элементы кода
/*q_e.h*/
#ifndef QUAD_EQUAT_H
#define QUAD_EQUAT_H

#include<stdint.h> /*здесь*/

double_t* solve_equation(
    const int64_t a,
    const int64_t b, 
    const int64_t c
);

#endif

/*q_e.c*/
#include "q_e.h"

double_t* solve_equation(
    /*...*/
)
{
    /*...*/
}


А как иначе? Заголовочный файл должен быть самодостаточным, а не так, что обязательно перед ним вызвать еще с десяток других...

@Harry так и как же мне тогда использовать тип данных int64_t. Опасаюсь что если использовать typedef то может возникнуть конфликт в файлах источниках.

Инклудьте stdint.h в свой хедер. Harry имеет в виду другое, что было бы неправильно не инклудить stdint.h и просить пользователя перед вашим хедером еще и инклудить stdint.h - это неудобно.

@HolyBlackCat Сенкс за разъяснение :) Неужели я так непонятно выразился? мне казалось, что понять меня можно было только так, как это сделали вы...

Всё-таки хотелось бы видеть в вопросе конкретные примеры кода. Без кода как-то не совсем понятно, что происходит, кто на ком стоял. Гуру то поняли, но вопрос должен быть понятен широкой аудитории, чтобы быть полезным. )

@Harry спасибо за ответ!

@HolyBlackCat так же спасибо!
